# Decrease the frequency of curl progress updates

Tags: curl

Is there a way to decrease the frequency with which `curl` updates its progress meter?

I need to download a large file in a CI pipeline. I want to see progress updates periodically, so that the CI pipeline is not automatically marked as "stuck". However, by default, `curl` updates its status quite often, so I end up with a pipeline log with thousands of lines like the following:

```
[...]
 33  189G   33 64.0G    0     0  8107k      0  6:48:27  2:18:09  4:30:18 4580k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8107k      0  6:48:28  2:18:10  4:30:18 4901k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8107k      0  6:48:29  2:18:11  4:30:18 5312k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8106k      0  6:48:31  2:18:12  4:30:19 5003k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8106k      0  6:48:32  2:18:13  4:30:19 4991k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8105k      0  6:48:34  2:18:14  4:30:20 4286k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8104k      0  6:48:36  2:18:15  4:30:21 3788k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8104k      0  6:48:38  2:18:16  4:30:22 3057k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8103k      0  6:48:40  2:18:17  4:30:23 2910k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8103k      0  6:48:41  2:18:18  4:30:23 2916k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8102k      0  6:48:43  2:18:19  4:30:24 3460k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8102k      0  6:48:44  2:18:20  4:30:24 3621k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8101k      0  6:48:45  2:18:21  4:30:24 3953k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8101k      0  6:48:47  2:18:22  4:30:25 4393k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8100k      0  6:48:48  2:18:23  4:30:25 4392k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8100k      0  6:48:50  2:18:24  4:30:26 4392k
 33  189G   33 64.1G    0     0  8099k      0  6:48:51  2:18:25  4:30:26 4394k
[...]
```

Comment: That's not a programming question, hence off-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't any such option to curl.

curl will update the progress meter at least once every second but when there's data being transferred it might do it (much) more frequently.

I've added [the idea](https://curl.se/docs/todo.html#Custom_progress_meter_update_int) in the curl TODO document!

Answer (score 2):

The best I could come up with is to silence `curl` altogether, and instead start a separate process which reports the file size every minute or longer.

```sh
(while true ; do sleep 60; ls -lSh filename.ext ; done) &
monitor_pid=$!
curl -O -C - --retry 999 --retry-max-time 0 --no-progress-meter ...
kill $monitor_pid
```